# Batch file to copy specific words from a text file to MS Word

Tags: batch-file, ms-word

I am working on a Natural Language Processing project for which I have to create a batch (.bat) file which will copy the contents of a file into MS-WORD.

The text to be copied is not uniform , but random tokens which are tagged, for example nouns like [Venice] ,adjectives will be tagged like (beautiful),determiners will be tagged like {the} etc.

Any help/suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Besides showing the code you've tried so far, also edit your question to show a sample source file and what the resulting Word file should be.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds far too simple - am I missunderstanding something?

```
copy yourfile.txt yourfile.rtf
yourfile.rtf
```